# Microsoft Word: Navigation Panel always messed up Headings

Tags: microsoft-word

In Microsoft Word's Navigation Panel, one can choose to show Headings, Pages, or Results.
When "Headings" is chosen, Headers will be shown, properly indented according to each one's level, Heading 1, Heading 2 etc...

My problem is, on my environment, ie

```
Edition Windows 11 Enterprise
Version 21H2
Installed on    ‎1/‎5/‎2022
OS build    22000.376
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.376.0

Microsoft® Word for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2111 Build 16.0.14701.20278) 64-bit
```

this always messed up. Quite often, when I open the file again, the indents are wrong, for example, Heading 2 shown with ident same to Heading 3.

I can manually adjust them, for example, change a messed up Heading 2 content to Heading 3, then change it back to Heading 2, then it'll be listed properly in Navigation Panel.

Is there a trick to save the effort?

Comment: Version of Word and OS? *(File > Account > About Word in Windows.)* This is not something I am seeing in Word 365 Version 2112 on Windows 10. Are you sure your heading levels are correct? Perhaps share a link to a sample document in which this is happening? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I've updated the windows and word version. I'm sure the heading levels are right .

Comment: A sample would help. I expect that this is related to styles updating but that is just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem after copy-pasting some text that had existing formatting. I would apply the Microsoft Word headings, but the Navigation was still getting it all wrong. I was able to resolve this by deleting all problematic headers and the lines before and after them and then just adding new text by typing it and highlighting the next text and applying the appropriate heading style.

Answer (score 4):

I just had that problem: a set of headings with exactly the same style applied were appearing in the Navigation Pane's Headings view with two different indentions.

In Word's Navigation pane (View > Show > Navigation Pane) there are three views: Headings, Pages, and Results. When I saw this inconsistency in the indention of same-level headings in Headings view, I clicked into Pages view and Results view, then back to Headings view, and the problem was resolved. I then closed the file and reopened it, and it's still fixed.

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There's not problem with this answer @rohitgupta. It worked flawlessly for me and answers the original question. This should be marked as the answer for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly switching between Page/Result tabs might resolve the problem.

[image: Headings/Page/Result tabs]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1231732)